# Bind Mac (10.10.2) to Active Directory through SSH tunnel

Tags: macos, ssh, active-directory, ldap, ssh-tunnel

I am attempting to Bind my Mac to a University AD server through an SSH tunnel. I have successfully created the tunnel and can access the directory by ldapsearch using the address localhost:389

The problem is that I wish to bind the computer through either the Directory Utility or dsconfigad but I get an error:

> dsconfigad: Authentication server could not be contacted. (5200)

Could it be because I need to port forward more ports than just 389? or would it be a limitation put in place by the Directory Admins?

Answer (score 0):

Active Directory is far more than LDAP - at the very least you'd need Kerberos, but it also tightly integrates with DNS (both SRV and A records), which'd require significant trickiness to fake over an SSL connection.

Realistically, I think you're going to need (at least) a full VPN connection to do this.